# siunitx changed something and when I comment it out, pdflatex freezes

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, siunitx

I was using a latex template (provided by a journal) to write a paper with the journal's `.cls` file . These are the style files provided separately:
`AMSbsy`; `AMSfonts`; `AMSgen`, `AMSsymb`, `natbib`, `upmath`

and these are the packages used inside the tex file:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{epstopdf, epsfig}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
```

Now I used package siunitx once in the tex file to get the

---

degree symbol correct and got this warning:
[image: warning after siunitx is used]

, but I later found it can be done with `$^{\circ}$`. 
Now, if I try to comment out `\usepackage{siunitx}`, and run `pdflatex`, it is going into an infinite loop. I need to run this file without using `siunitx` as I cant risk changing some styles from what the journal requires. Any solution?
Thanks.

Comment: Although your question is understandable as it stands, it would greatly benefit from a proper _MWE_ http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe

Comment: does the journal _really_ say to use epsfig? (in any case don't do that, just use graphicx that you are already loading.